# How to use isalpha to loop back when an alphabetical character isn't entered

Tags: python

I am a little confused as to why the loop ends. I was trying to make it so that if someone inputs numbers it loops back and asks the question again however it seems to just end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
while True:
  first_name = input("Please enter your first name. ")
  try:
    if first_name.isalpha() == False:
      print("Please don't use alphanumeric characters ")
  except:
    if first_name.isalpha() == True:
      print()
  else:
    break
```

Comment: try-except is for catching exceptions but why should one be raised?

Answer (score 0):

The `try-except-else` and `if-else` blocks seem to be kind of mixed up. The `except` block will only be executed if an exception is thrown within the `try:` block body, and this doesn't happen normally in this code.

The `else:` block attached to `try:` will be executed every time the `try: block *doesn't* throw an exception. So in this case it will execute the`break` statement every time.

Comment: Thanks for the response I'll give this a try later today.